# Reactjs and Superagent pt3

Tags: reactjs, superagent

I'm making progress on this app. I'm able to access and render the list of ingredients now I need to do the same with the name of the recipe. Postman indicates that it is under recipes.body.matches[0].sourceDisplayName. I created another function, similar to what got me the ingredients. Getting the following error...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```js
import React from 'react';
import Request from 'superagent';
import _ from 'lodash';

export class Yum extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            searchQuery: 'onion',
            recipe: {
                ingredients: []
            }
        };

        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
        this.queryUpdate = this.queryUpdate.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.search(this.state.searchQuery);
    }

    render(){
        //const title = 'Onion Soup'; // Get this from somwhere else ?
        const {recipe, searchQuery} = this.state; // Get state properties
        const displayName = _.get(recipe, 'sourceDisplayName').map((sourceDisplayName) => {
            return (<h4>{displayName}</h4>)
        });

        const listItems = _.get(recipe, 'ingredients', []).map((ingredient, sourceDisplayName) => {
            return (<h5>{ingredient}</h5>);
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.queryUpdate} type="text" value={searchQuery} />

                <h4>{displayName}</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li>{listItems}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    queryUpdate(event) {
        const searchQuery = event.target.value; // Get new value from DOM event
        this.setState({searchQuery}); // Save to state
        this.search(searchQuery); // Search
    }

    search(searchQuery) {
        const url = `http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=5129dd16&_app_key=9772f1db10ba433223ad4e765dc2b537&q=${searchQuery}&maxResult=1`
        Request.get(url).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                recipe: response.body.matches[0]
            });
        });
    }
}

export default Yum;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pass props to constructor(props) and super(props) , and where is sourceDisplayName code ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by sourceDisplayName code.